# Почему не работает js код на IE любой версии?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**Почему не работает js код на IE любой версии?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

```
var titleSearch = `
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1>Поиск <small>`+ quantityProduct +`</small></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**P.S.**
Решил сделать вопрос-ответ по причине того, что на поиски ответа убил порядком нескольких дней (а потом еще пару дней менял все на кавычки), надеюсь кому-либо это будет полезно. (Если есть другое решение, буду рад ответам в комментарии).

**IE не поддерживает шаблонные строки ``.**
Весь код, который содержит в себе подобные символы `, придется переписать на кавычки и конкатенацию *(сложение, пример: "Hello" + "world!")*.

**Решение:**

```
var titleSearch = '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-sm-6">' +
            '<div class="page-title">' +
                '<h1>Поиск <small>(Всего 1 товар)</small></h1>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';
```

Comment: Ну, конечно вроде не дубль и польза есть, но в случае таких специфических ошибок стоит для начала проверять поддержку того или иного синтаксиса: https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

Comment: @MedvedevDev Проверяю, но в этот раз я и подумать не мог что такая годная вещь как строк.лит. могут не работать в IE.

Comment: все новое - плохо поддерживаемое и годное (ну или почти годное)

Comment: IE поддерживает строковые литералы, он не поддерживает шаблонные строки. Это не одно и то же.

Comment: «а потом еще пару дней менял все на кавычки» — а можно было просто поставить babel

Comment: @yar85 Понял, спасибо